# tutorial vs API refrence: What is the diffrence?

Tags: python, django, iphone, django-rest-framework, django-tables2

In many sites like: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io
we see two sections:

```
1-tutorial
2-API-reference
```

what is the two section explain?
what is the difference of them?

If we want to use from library How I can start and implementation it?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

A tutorial is generally a guided hands-on lesson on how to use an API, including examples, FAQs, and general advice. Very useful when you are not too familiar with the library and want to understand what it does, what it can be used for, and how to use it.

API reference is going to be specific documentation on the API (the functions/data that is accessible to you as the developer), much more technical and detailed, very useful when you have context and are looking for a specific tool, or trying to debug a specific problem.

Start with the tutorial, then later refer to the API documentation when you want more detail. A well documented API is incredibly useful.